# Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, dql

I am trying to get the id from a entity object.

The  Code

```
public function findByName($name)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->where('u.name  = :name');
    $qp->setParameter('name', $name);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And I am calling the function like this

```
$Obj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
$idName=$Obj->findByName('Sarah');
var_dump($idName->getId());
```

I am getting an error for this part `var_dump($idName->getId());`.

I am getting the whole Object and I just want the Id. It doesn't work.

`$idName` dumps to this:

```
@array(1) {<br>
[0]=> object(UserBundle\Entity\User)#2339 (2) { <br>
["id":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> int(2) ["name":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> string(8) "Sarah" <br>
} }
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($idName);` to make sure it's an object?

Comment: Yes I am getting `array(1) { [0]=> object(UserBundle\Entity\User)#2339 (2) { ["id":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> int(2) ["name":"UserBundle\Entity\User":private]=> string(5) "Sarah" } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findBy...` always returns an array of found entities (even if there is just one found for the criteria). Use `findOneBy...` to always get only the first entity returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `$idName` is an `@array(1)`, not an object. Try using this to get to it

```
var_dump($idName[0]->getId());
```

Comment: Is there any just to get it without array?

Comment: @JooniJoon I have no idea. I didn't write Symfony. But if it's returning an array then it could possibly return more than one object